# Can't convert Timedelta Object to numeric value in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, timedelta

I have a data frame with type: **String** , i want to convert the delta column into total hours

```
          deltas
0     2 days 12:19:00
1        04:45:00
2     3 days 06:41:00
3     5 days 01:55:00
4        13:57:00
```

Desired Output:

```
          deltas
0      60 hours
1       4 hours
```

I tried `pd.to_timedelta()` but i get this error `only leading negative signs are allowed` and i am totally stuck in this

Comment: so are those strings? or TimeDelta objects? if you already have timeDelta objects why would you call to_timedelta?

Comment: @JoranBeasley yes

Comment: works fine for me with sample data.

Comment: same ... `df = pandas.DataFrame({'s':['2 days 12:19:00','04:45:00','3 days 06:41:00','5 days 01:55:00','13:57:00']}); pandas.to_timedelta(df['s'])`

Answer (score 0):

To get the number of hours as *int* run:

```
(pd.to_timedelta(df.s) / np.timedelta64(1, 'h')).astype(int)
```

The first step is to convert the string representation of *Timedelta* to
**actual** *Timedelta*.
Then divide it by 1 hour and convert to *int*.